# Python kivy doesn't work when I convert my code to exe

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, auto-py-to-exe

As a code, it works without any problems but when I convert it to exe, I get Unable to get window, abort error I tried all the solutions I found in the forums Can a person who can convert this code to exe for me tell me how he did it?

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFloatingActionButton


class main(BoxLayout,MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        self.a = MDTextField(size_hint_y=.1, hint_text="Write for translate", helper_text="Press the button for translate",helper_text_mode="on_focus", icon_right="cursor-text", size_hint_x=None, width=300,pos_hint={'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.96})
        self.add_widget(self.a)
        self.b = MDFloatingActionButton(size_hint_y=.1, icon='translate',pos_hint={'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.96})
        self.add_widget(self.b)
        self.b.bind(on_release=self.show_data)
        self.layout = BoxLayout(size_hint_y=.8)
        self.add_widget(self.layout)

    def show_data(self, show):
        self.list = self.a.text.split()
        for i in range(len(self.list)):
            if not self.list[i].endswith(".png"):
                self.list[i] += ".png"
        print(self.list)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.call)

    def call(self, call):
        self.numb = 0
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.do, 0.7)

    def do(self, do):
        if (self.numb < len(self.list)):
            self.layout.clear_widgets()
            self.layout.add_widget(Image(source=self.list[self.numb]))
            self.numb += 1
        else:
            self.numb = 0
            self.list = [self.a.text]
            Clock.unschedule(self.do)
            self.layout.clear_widgets()


class app(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app().run()
```

I tried with Cx_freeze , uninstalling kivy and other things can someone convert to exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully converted your code to an exe using `pyinstaller`. Here is the `spec` file that I used (it assumes that your python file is named `main.py`):

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
```

Note the `kivy_deps` inclusion.

Comment: Are you sure the exe will work bc I can convert exe too but when I open the exe I get the Unable to get window , abort error

Comment: I can only say that it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Kivy needs some DLLs, and you have to help the exe maker know where those DLLs are.

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html?highlight=window